# Simple Javascript text editor or set of functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-editor

I need a simple javascript (possibly with jQuery) text/html editor. I've done a lot of search and found loads of plugins, but most of them are way too 'complete' for what I'm seeking.

Actually, all I want is a set of functions, not complex UI nor fancy toolbars. Those function would be basically,

- Change font family to one of a limited predefined set (there should be the possibility to have multiple font faces at the same time, on the container)
- Change font size
- Change font colour
- Change format style (bold, italic, underline, etc)

What you would recommend? Should I write my own plugin?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Aloha](http://www.aloha-editor.org/) is the best in WYSIWYG online editors. They have nice [wiki](http://www.aloha-editor.org/guides/develop_aloha.html) as well

Answer (score 2):

All web editors work pretty simple and relay on Browser functionality.

You can make any field of your HTML page editable by setting the attribute  `contenteditable="true"`  on the element and calling: `$('#edit').designMode = "on";` after the page load

You can change the font of your selection with

```
document.execCommand("fontname", false, "Courier New");
```

the size with

```
document.execCommand("fontsize", false, "20");
```

the color with

```
document.execCommand("ForeColor", false, "green");
```

Bold, Italic with:

```
document.execCommand("bold", false);
document.execCommand("italic", false);
```

Here is a sample test page I created (which sadly only works in FF, because in the other browsers he looses the selection of your text when you click a button)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>HTML5 Demo: ContentEditable</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="onload()">
        <h2>Go ahead, edit away!</h2>
        <div id="editarea"></div>
        <!-- 'contenteditable="true"' need so the user can select the element and edit it's text-->
        <section contenteditable="true">
            <p>
                Here's a typical paragraph element
            </p>
            <div contenteditable="true">
                <p>
                    hallo welt
                </p>
            </div>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    and now a list
                </li>
            </ol>
        </section>
    </body>
    <script>
        function onload() {
            // needed for the resize boxes in IE
            document.designMode = "on"
            $('#editarea').append($('<button>').html("fontname").click(function() {
                document.execCommand("fontname", false, "Courier New");
            }));
            $('#editarea').append($('<button>').html("fontsize").click(function() {
                document.execCommand("fontsize", false, "20");
            }));
            $('#editarea').append($('<button>').html("changeSize").click(function() {
                document.execCommand("ForeColor", false, "green");
            }));
            $('#editarea').append($('<button>').html("bold").click(function() {
                document.execCommand("bold", false);
            }));
            $('#editarea').append($('<button>').html("italic").click(function() {
                document.execCommand("italic", false);
            }));
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

PS in case you need more, you should look at [Aloha](http://aloha-editor.org/) editor

Answer (score 1):

extjs has a really nice once, but the framework is fairly bloated.

Otherwise, check for jquery plugins I am sure there are heaps. The extjs one is still my favourite though.

Answer (score 1):

[TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) is a great one! You can specify exactly what you want to make available to your users and it is very easy to implement.

It is quite 'complete' but if you specify what you want to make available (and change the theme to something more spartan if you like) you can get a quite minimalistic gui.

It's a good solution that beats writing your own IMHO.

[This is an example](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/listbox_splitbutton.php) that shows a gui that is quite a bit simpler than the full version, just to show the flexibility of their system. You can sculpt it to your exact specifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own or use plugins. Here is the basic idea from me.

HTML:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
<button id="make-bold">Make bold</button>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('make-bold').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
    var tag = document.createElement('strong');

    range.surroundContents(tag);
    selection.addRange(range);
});
```

Live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/im4aLL/Lyusxq3p/

I pullout the basic idea by this and finally made something which i use in my future projects.

I made EasyEditor - https://github.com/im4aLL/easyeditor from above concept. There are lot more things to do. Like when are wrapping a node you need to check wheather that selection already wrapped with other node or same node. Also there are lot of functions you need to overcome.

Or you may try my lightweight plugin which i made for guys like you who need full flexible solution to integrate it with another application.

#### Here's the demo and documentation for use EasyEditor

- Demo: http://habibhadi.com/lab/easyeditor/
- Examples: http://habibhadi.com/lab/easyeditor/examples.html
- Documentation: http://habibhadi.com/lab/easyeditor/documentation.html

#### Usage

http://habibhadi.com/lab/easyeditor/default-example.html